# Having an issue with running Tensorflow 2 on a local machine

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I managed to successfully install Tensorflow 2 on windows with object detection. After running the command:

python model_main_tf2.py --pipeline_config_path=ssd_efficientdet_d0_512x512_coco17_tpu-8.config --model.dir=training --alsologtostderr

I get this Traceback:

```
W0724 22:39:24.257511 12060 deprecation.py:350] From C:\Users\malde\anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:1176: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.cast` instead.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\malde\Documents\TF2\models\research\object_detection\model_main_tf2.py", line 114, in <module>
    tf.compat.v1.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\malde\anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 36, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "C:\Users\malde\anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 308, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "C:\Users\malde\anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 254, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "C:\Users\malde\Documents\TF2\models\research\object_detection\model_main_tf2.py", line 105, in main
    model_lib_v2.train_loop(
  File "C:\Users\malde\anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py", line 591, in train_loop
    os.path.join(model_dir, 'train'))
  File "C:\Users\malde\anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\ntpath.py", line 78, in join
    path = os.fspath(path)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

Has anyone else encountered this issue and has been able to resolve it?

I haven't been able to find much info online about this error. Looks like someone has been able to fix it by recreating csv files, but it did not help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like `model_dir` is None. I guess the argument in your command should be `--model_dir=training`.